# Deserialize data that comes from laravel in vuejs

Tags: json, vue.js, serialization

I fetched a serialize data from laravel in my vuejs app and now I can not deserialize the data with common methods like JSON.parse() , what I should to do exactly?
I know that this question is simple but I am really confused

sample of my serialized data:

```
a:1:{s:32:"9d02074b55380f2b5a98b4e99f59bbfe";a:7:{s:2:"id";s:3:"117";s:4:"name";s:19:"Deine Pizza, medium";s:5:"price";d:7.5;s:3:"qty";d:1;s:7:"options";a:8:{s:3:"_al";s:8:"x20RJkN6";s:3:"_pi";s:3:"117";s:3:"_hp";s:1:"1";s:3:"_fl";s:0:"";s:3:"_ca";s:2:"13";s:22:"Classic-Teig {11}[E4S]";s:1:"0";s:44:"Pizza mit wÃ¼rzigem KÃ¤se im Rand {191}[TQo]";s:4:"2.35";s:25:"Bauernschinken {195}[e0H]";s:4:"2.35";}s:5:"rowid";s:32:"9d02074b55380f2b5a98b4e99f59bbfe";s:8:"subtotal";d:7.5;}}
```

Comment: You should at least format your code...

Comment: @YomS. thanks for your response, I serialized my data before in Laravel app and this is serialized data format